# any plugins that remove unused CSS and save new CSS file?

Tags: html, css

Dust me selectors is installed but cant find anyway of saving the css minus the unused lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=66

This is also nice

see this video http://www.channels.com/episodes/show/6870707/Episode-180-Finding-Unused-CSS

And see here how to convert Dust-me selector's CSV to CSS

http://www.railsonwave.com/2007/10/22/dust-me-csv-to-css-with-rake/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this resource: [CSS cleaner and optimiser](http://www.cleancss.com/). Maybe it's what you're looking for, but as always, [Google](http://www.google.com) is your friend too :)

[Liquidicity](http://www.gosquared.com/liquidicity/archives/164) is a PHP plugin you can try, or another option I think is [CSS Tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks kyle, but the primary function needs to be removing UNUSED css, so probably needs to be some kind of browser plugin?

Comment: Aha, there was a tool called CSS Checker that could do exactly that, but the site seems to be down. Hold on I'll get you a link from somewhere else.

Comment: http://services.immike.net/css-checker/ there's the broken link, but I can't find it anywhere else.. Hope one of the other tools we posted helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Firefox user, there are some Plugins that do what you want - although they are more likely to suggest what is unused, so you can decide what to remove (as something might be used on Page A, but not Page B)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10704

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392

Answer (score -2):

None of above does the job easily...
So, that's the good one (and the payment one): https://unused-css.com/
I haven't tryied it yet but seems to do what you need!

Comparative: http://hackadelic.com/remove-unused-css-affordable-css-optimizer-service